# Get IIS Sites data using loop

Tags: iis, server, iis-7, appcmd

I have been trying to automate the process of migrating the IIS sites. But I am not able to loop through the sites using batch script.
I want to loop through the output of the list sites command and pass the specific values from this to the next command like id and site name.

**appcmd list sites /text:id** --> this will give site id.

I want these sites ids to be used to create a zip file by appending the id to the name parameter which is also returned using appcmd command.

Can anyone help me out in this;

Comment: Unless you believe you can reinvent a better wheel than Microsoft's Web Deployment Tool, you shouldn't waste time on such.

Comment: If you use web deploy to migrate IIS site, it will auto get all sites information and package them. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: I need to get the sites that are started and not in the stopped state